# Visual Studio 2019 How to disable outlining

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

How do I permanently disable outlining in Visual Studio 2019. Specifically for Javascript files, without having to manually switch it off every single time I open a file.

Comment: Right click → Outlining → Stop Outlining?

Comment: Updated my question to make my intent clearer.